# Chance of winning when you are ahead a flip coin game

Tags: probability

Two players, $A$ and $B$, alternately and independently flip a coin and the player wins only when he gets a head, and the other player gets the tail. Each round they will flip coin at the same time. If the coin is fair, and let’s assume there is infinitely round until one win. At the end, either player $A$ or $B$ will win, so the probability of player $A$ win plus probability of player $B$ win should equal to $100\%$.

The question I tried to solve is this:  In the above question, each win counts as one point, each loss counts as $-1$ point, whoever gets $3$ points first wins. (Game over when score is 3: -3).Now assume player $A$ wins one point at sometime. So the score are player A : player B is 1: -1; Then, what’s the probability player $A$ wins the game after that. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Does $B$ win the game if the first three flips are $H, H, T$?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: You haven't really answered DreiCleaner's question.  Do you mean a player wins if that player obtains a head, then the other player obtains a tail on the next throw?

Comment: You still haven't addressed my question.  Does a player win if that player obtains a head, then the other player obtains a tail on the next throw?  Notice the use of the word *then*.

Comment: Yes Taussig, both players take turn to throw coin and then if player A obtains a head, and player B obtains a tail, then player A win and get 1 point and player B lost 1 point. If player B obtains head and player A obtains tail, then player B win and get 1 point and player A lost 1 point. Otherwise nobody get points and game continue

Comment: Look up [Gambler's ruin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin).  Your situation is the same as the fair coin flip except that you have 1/2 chance of a tie.  We can ignore the ties.  A needs to gain 2 points to win, B needs to gain 4, so A has $\frac 4{2+4}=\frac 23$ chance of winning the game.

Comment: Thanks Ross, that is the result I got too. Thanks for the Gambler’s ruin reference.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to see that the probabilities of **A** win, lose, and draw **one** game are

$\frac14,\; \frac14,\;$  and $\;\frac12$ respectively

Let there be $3\,$ *states,* **D,W,L** (in the last game you  drew, won and  lost respectively.)

Finally, let $d,w,l$ be the probabilities that you (ultimately) win from **D**, **W** and **L** Since the game starts with **A** up by $1$ game, we  seek the probability that we ultimately win starting from **W**

Note that from any stage you can draw and return to **D** with $Pr = 1/2$.

Thus the *Pr* equation to reflect various transitions that can take place to move to **D**, move to **W** or move to **L** will be given by the equation

$d = d/2 + w/4 + l/4\quad$   **[I]**

Similarly, $w = d/2 + (1/4)*1 +l/4\quad$ **[II]**

(Note that the second term , a win from **W** completes a win for **A**)

$l =  d/2 + w/4 + (1/4)*0 \quad$ [III]

(Note that a loss from **l** will end the game for **A**)

solving these $3$ linear equations gives us

$w = \frac35,\quad l = \frac25,\quad d = \frac12\;$(as expected)

The answer sought is $\frac35$

---

**PS** In a hurry, I read that **A** needs to be **ahead** of **B** by $2$ points to win, whereas you want her to win two *more* points. Anyway, having laid down the template, you should be able to solve on your own now. Just add  states, **WW** and **LL** and proceed as before.

**PPS** I'm more confused after reading some clarifications you have added. **A** had a difference of two $(1 - (-1))$ and by winning one more the scores are $2,-2$ so the **difference** is $4$, idk whether in your scheme of things, **A** has won or not, anyway you can proceed further on your own. I think you have *devised* this game yourself, giving plus and minus points together is not really a good idea, it doesn't add anything to the game.

Either games just have win or lose, or have a win-draw-lose system like chess, soccer, checkers.

Comment: Thanks very much, that is great help, I think I should be able to solve it now.

Comment: Glad to be of help !

Answer (score 0):

I assume from the title of the question, that you want to know the chance A will win *given that he went first and has already flipped heads*.  Please rephrase the problem if that's not what you wanted.

The chance is either $2/3$ or $3/4$ depending on the form of the game.  If there are "rounds", and you only win by flipping a head and your opponent flipping a tail on the same round, then it's $3/4$.  If any run of a heads by one player and a tails by the other player wins, then it's $2/3$.

If there are rounds, and you flipped first, then if the opponent flips tails you win that 50% and the other 50% you are back to even, so your total chance of winning is 50% plus half of the other 50%, or $3/4$.

If there are not rounds, you will win if your opponent flips tails, lose if your opponent flips head and you next flip tails, and be back to where you started if you both flip heads.  So 50% to win, 25% to lose, and 25% to get back to where you started (which again will apportion its final results 2:1 in your favor), will give you a $2/3$ chance of winning.

Interesting is to analyze the chance the first player wins.  If you are using "rounds", this is obviously $1/2$ before you start.  But if any heads-then-tails sequence wins, the first player has a $5/9$ chance of winning.  For consider the first two flips:

H T  --- first player wins
H H  --- we know the first player wins $1/3$ of the time with this start (since someone who just flipped heads has a $2/3$ chance)
T H --- we know the first player wins $1/3$ of the time with this start
T T ---no one has a heads yet, so we are back where we started.

As before we can ignore the $1/4$ of the time you get back to where you started, and the first player wins $1/3+1/9+1/9=5/9$ of the rest of the time.

Comment: Thanks C Monsour, and sorry, I guess my question title is misleading. Let me try again. Two players, A and B, each round, they both flip a coin at the same time. If one flip head, the other flip a tail then whoever flip the head won and get one point and the other player loses one point. Otherwise it is a tie, no point awarded. At the beginning, both players has zero points and Let’s say, in some point, the player A ahead by one point. I.e, player A: 1 point, player B: -1 point. Again, let’s assume player win the game by gain 3 points. Then, what’s the chance player A win the game at the end.